# Jquery Select one object but hide others of the same type

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm  new to programming and I've never posted on here before but this problem should be fairly  simple yet I can't  get it. It goes beyond the basics for me. I have 5 objects all with the same div class. I've experimented with hiding classes and such but my goal is to use an event handler and jquery selectors to select the one object and hide or detach the rest. My code is probably pretty ugly but I'm  working toward an answer.However once the object that wasn't hidden is clicked again I want the others to reappear.

Comment: If you have a click handler, then I would hide all with matching class and then show "this".

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

- `.not(this)` selects every other element of the common class except from the selected one
- `.toggle()` keeps changing the elements' status from hidden to visible and back forever...

```js
$('.aa').click(function(){
  $('.aa').not(this).toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aa">1</div>
<div class="aa">2</div>
<div class="aa">3</div>
<div class="aa">4</div>
<div class="aa">5</div>
```

Comment: If hypothetically there was a hidden element too and had the same class and we'd like to keep it always hidden, then I guess we'd have to use id-selectors since it won't be able to distinguish it from the other hidden-by-click elements any other way (unless we play with hidden <> display:none e.t.c.) anyway let's not complicate things...

Comment: You can hide all by your selector and then show only $(this)

Comment: You're right ezhikov, that was my first thought too, it's just not as clean as the solution above.